# What can I use if I want't to display a top 10 list of records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a a room booking system where, a user can choose a room, and then book timeslots for that given room.

I wan't to extend my system a bit, with the option to have a top 10 list of the most booked rooms.

You can see my database, and it's foreign keys here:

[image]

I know that I can count all of my bookings that have a room_id of 2 fx:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `bookings` WHERE `room_id` = 2
```

But what I want to achive, is having list that would look something like this:

```
Room1 = 84 bookings
Room2 = 70 bookings
Room3 = 54 bookings
etc.
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as bCount, room_id 
FROM `bookings`
GROUP BY room_id
ORDER BY bCount
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. That was a bit more than a pointer. However, they are now ordered with the room that's least booked at the top, and the most booked at the bottom. How do I reverse that?

Comment: @Adnaves are you *that* unfamiliar with sorting arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use GROUP BY Clause

```
SELECT Count(*) as Count , room_id
FROM bookings
GROUP BY room_id
ORDER BY Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query,

```
   select count(*) as booking_count , room_id as room from `bookings`
   group by room order by booking_count
```